# Azure Function fails to load assemblies after running fine for a while

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have a function listening to blob storage that have inserts frequently, though at times rarely enough for the function to go idle.

It is set up in a way that it contains some custom DLL's in the bin folder, and the actual function itself is merely calling a run method in one of those assemblies. This works fine. Most of the time.

My problem is, that if I let it run for a while it will suddenly fail to load my custom assemblies, with the following error message:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.EventHandlerFunctionMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.EventHandlerFunction ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'MyAssembly.MyFunctions.EventHandlerFunction' from assembly 'MyAssembly.MyFunctions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.   at async Submission#0.Run(Stream blob,String name,TraceWriter log) at  : 19   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)   at Submission#0.Run(Stream blob,String name,TraceWriter log)    End of inner exception   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,Object[] arguments,Signature sig,Boolean constructor)   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,Object[] parameters,Object[] arguments)   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj,BindingFlags invokeAttr,Binder binder,Object[] parameters,CultureInfo culture)   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.DotNetFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context)   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters)   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`1.InvokeAsync[TReflected](Object[] arguments)   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,Object[] invokeParameters,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameters,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationToken…
```

As you can see from the stacktrace, my assembly (renamed MyAssembly.MyFunctions), suddenly fails to load. It will manage to recover on it's own, but the downtime and "dropped" blobs are somewhere around 1/5th of my blobs.

This seems dumb. While I realize I could mitigate this by reacting to that exception and reinserting the blob, this just seems like a waste of resources.

My guess is that the azure functions runtime sometimes fails to load dlls after being idle. Has anyone experienced this and found a way to solve it?

**UPDATE:** My Function looks like this:

```
    #r "MyAssembly.MyFunctions.dll"

    public static async Task Run(Stream blob, string name, TraceWriter log)
    {
        try {
            await new EventHandlerFunction().Run(name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.Error(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe it would be a good idea to open this directly on github https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but figured I'd give it a go here first for a day or two.

Comment: Definitely not expected behavior. Can you share your function app name or an execution ID so we can take a closer look at what is going on here?

Comment: For anyone following, this is now being investigated here: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1338

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone stumbling on this:

The answer was that multiple versions of the same assemblies were located in the same function app, in different bin folders (different functions). Apparently, it would sometimes find a different version when loading assemblies, and that would cause the mentioned error.

There are two solutions:

1. Preferably, start using the VS2017 tooling to build, test, and publish your functions. This puts all assemblies
   in the same bin folder and the whole development and publishing
   process resembles that of Webjobs.
2. Alternatively, put all your assemblies in a shared folder, and
   reference that rather than specific bin folder for each function.

Comment: Also of note: this effectively means that you shouldn't have multiple functions in the same function app, unless they always share the same assemblies. It's impossible to update the assembly of one function while not updating the other functions, as they are shared.

Comment: Since I recently received an upvote for this reponse... The recommended practice as of 2020 is to not publish seperate function projects to the same function app like you would a webjob, but have dedicated function apps for each project in VS.